# Bind controller data to the html page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind data to the HTML page as below but data is not binding.

```
<body ng-app="Profileapp" ng-controller="ProfileController" >
    {{username}}
</body>
```

My controller is

```
var app = angular.module('Profileapp',['ngFlash']);
app.controller('ProfileController',['$scope','$http','$window','Flash',function($scope,$http,$window,Flash) {
    $scope.username = "sachin yadav";
}])
```

Comment: could you please check the console for errors?

Comment: Have you included all the dependent js files including that of ngFlash?

Comment: There is no error in console.

Comment: and i have included all files for angular Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. It is working fine below without the flash plugin. Check if there is any css property that is overshadowing your body. And also make sure all the dependencies for flash have been included.

```js
var app = angular.module('Profileapp',[]);
app.controller('ProfileController',['$scope','$http','$window',function($scope,$http,$window) {
    $scope.username = "sachin yadav";
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="Profileapp" ng-controller="ProfileController" >
    {{username}}
</body>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? The above snippet is working fine, it must be generated from somewhere else in your code. Check ur console if there are any errors

Comment: i tried into ejs file its working file but not in html.

Comment: What is your app engine. Is it ejs or html? I mean from backend?

Comment: was html but now i am using ejs so i changed it to ejs.

Comment: So it will work with ejs, change it back to html and check if it is working